# Scraping using codeigniter and i need title and custom link

Tags: html, codeigniter, web-scraping

```
<div id="archive_content_block">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
         <div class="archive_cat_caption">
            <h4>অর্থনীতি</h4>
        </div>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>&nbsp;
          <a href="http://67.227.189.112/~rtvnews24/economy/2126/বাধ্যতামূলক-করারোপের-প্রস্তাব-অর্থমন্ত্রীর">
         <font style="color:rgb(33, 33, 33)">বাধ্যতামূলক করারোপের প্রস্তাব অর্থমন্ত্রীর</font>
        </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
     <div class="archive_cat_caption">
        <h4>খেলাধুলা</h4>
     </div>
     <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>&nbsp;<a href="http://67.227.189.112/~rtvnews24/sports/2096/অস্ট্রেলিয়া-রেকর্ড"><font style="color:rgb(33, 33, 33)">অস্ট্রেলিয়া রেকর্ড</font></a></li> 
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[this is my scraping html page code]

here i have a function which for get scraping title and link. but not work

```
   public function get_dom()
    {   
    $this->load->library('scraping');
    $date = date('Y/m/d');  // custom date
    $url = "http://67.227.189.112/~rtvnews24/archive/$date";  //my link
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $row =   $html->find('div.archive_content_block',0);  // select content 
    foreach($row->find('div.archive_cat_caption', 0) as $title) {
      echo $title->find('h4', 0)->plaintext.'</br>'; //title
         foreach($row->find('ul',0) as $link) {
          echo $link->find('li',0)->find('a', 0)->href.'</br>'; //link
            }
     }
  }
```

here i am try to get title and link. please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you expect. What did you get. "here i have a function which for get scrapping title and link. but not work " is not very useful or insightful for anyone trying to help you.